# How can I specify aspect ratio in BubbleChart3D so as to keep the bubbles spherical?

Tags: graphics

I would like to make a 3D bubble chart with an aspect ratio of 0.3. But when I give `BubbleChart3D` the option `AspectRatio -> 0.3`, the bubbles aspect ratio also changes, squashing the bubbles. I have wasted much time and I didn't get the desired result. I tried to apply functions like `Scale` and set `BoxRatios` but didn't get a positive result.

[image: original]
[image: after the change]

How can I cope with this problem?

```
BubbleChart3D[
 {Join[mean[[;; , ;; 3]], Partition[σ, 1], 2]}~Flatten~1
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}
 , AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}
 , BubbleScale -> "Diameter"
 , ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}
 , ViewPoint -> {-1, 0., 0.}
 , FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 0}}
 , FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]
 , Boxed -> True
 , ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[0.7 - 0.7 #1, 0.7] &)
 , Lighting -> 
     {{"Ambient", LightGray}, {"Directional", Gray, {20000, 15000, 100000}}}
 , AspectRatio -> 0.3
 , BoxRatios -> Automatic
 , ImageSize -> {600, 200}
 ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another way to do it. I define a chart element function that makes the bubbles ellipsoids having principal axes calculated to reverse the distortion introduced by changing the z-axis box ratio.

```
coords = Flatten[CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 3, 2}}], 2];
SeedRandom[42]; vals = RandomReal[1, Length@coords];
bubbles = MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {coords, vals}];

With[{zAspect = .3, λ = .2}},
  BubbleChart3D[bubbles,
    ChartElementFunction -> 
      (Ellipsoid[#2[[;; 3]], λ #2[[4]] {1, 1, 1/zAspect/GoldenRatio}] &),
    Axes -> True,
    AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
    AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
    BubbleScale -> "Diameter",
    FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
    Boxed -> True,
    ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[.3 + .7 (1 - #1), 0.5] &),
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, zAspect},
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.04],
    ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image: bubbles]

Comment: Huge help, thank you. I am going to be that person who points out the nearly-insignificant typo. You have "With[{zAspect = .3, λ = .2}}," and it needs to be "With[{zAspect = .3, λ = .2}," .

Comment: Ah, something which is a little more worth mentioning, looks like if you use "ChartElementFunction -> (Ellipsoid[#2[[;; 3]], 
    0.3 #2[[4]] {1, 1, 1}] &)," at the very end (say, after "BoxRatios -> {1, 1, zAspect},") then the shapes are perfect spheres again.

Answer (score 8):

A somewhat hacky fix is to inspect what's inside and change it:

```
postprocessBubbleChart3D[in_] := 
  With[{br = Quiet[BoxRatios /. AbsoluteOptions[in, BoxRatios]]},
    (
      in /. GeometricTransformation3DBox[{s_SphereBox}, {m_?MatrixQ, v_}] :> 
        GeometricTransformation3DBox[s, {m/br, v}]

    ) /; VectorQ[br]
  ]

postprocessBubbleChart3D[in_] := in
```

Some fake data:

```
chart = BubbleChart3D[Select[RandomReal[1, {50, 4}], Min[#[[2]], #[[3]]] > 0.5 &], BoxRatios -> Automatic];
```

Test:

```
{chart, postprocessBubbleChart3D[chart]}
```

[image]